# htaccess redirect domain a.com to b.com/blog with keep a.com adress

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I want redirect domain a.com to b.com/blog
but want keep a.com adress in browser bar. 
 
 
I currently have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: is a.com a parked domain?

Comment: a. com and b.com is a same serwer

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.** It would be quite a security hole for a browser to be redirected to a different domain without the address bar showing this!

You could use iFrames ... but I would first question why you want to do this at all.